# Images not showing on github pages, but shows in "preview" on remote repository

Tags: github, github-pages, hugo

I recently created a website using Hugo, and when running `hugo server`, the images compiled fine. I then pushed all of my files to git, and no images appeared on the GitHub page, EXCEPT for the one on my main page. This image is located at `static/main.jpg`. My other images were also located in `static`. Moreover, when the images were located in `static`, the 'preview' for the post in which the images are did not render the images either.

I found online that Jekyll is used, and therefore requires a folder `docs/assets`. I created this, and put all images (except for the one which works in `static`) in `assets`. However, the images still can not be found on the GitHub page, however interestingly, they do now show in the 'preview' for the post in question.

My file structure is as follows:

```
content
- homepage
- post
-- photogallery.md (where the issue is occurring)
- _index.md (where the working image is)
doc/assets
- dm1.jpg (and all other images)
static
- main.jpg (working image)
hugo.toml
```

Within `_index.md` (the working image), I have `<img src="main.jpg" alt="me">`, and within `photogallery.md` (the other images), I have `<img src="/docs/assets/dm1.jpg" alt="dartmouth 1" width="225">` (of course with different file names for each image).

The same issue is happening for a pdf I have linked in a separate post. It almost seems like my assets folder can only be reached by files in the root directory.

Nothing I have tried has worked (pathname changes, checking capitalization/exact file names, setting `canonifyURLs = true` in `hugo.toml`, etc). I would expect for an image in the same file path as a functioning image would also function, but this is not the case. Further, I would expect that if images are showing in the preview in the remote repository, that they would also show up in the GitHub page.

Answer (score 0):

Images in the static folder can be referenced using `imagename.jpg` or `/imagename.jpg`.

The first one only works when you are in the homepage. The second one works from any page.

Files in assets cannot be referenced using their path. These files are ONLY available when they pass through a Hugo variable called [resources](https://gohugo.io/methods/page/resources/).